# Removing Records with matching different fields using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, duplicates

I have a MySQL table with data that looks like this:

```
EventID_1   Event_ID2   SomeInfo    MoreInfo    YetMoreInfo
1              5           blah        blah        blah
5              1           Boo         boo         Boo
4              9           foo         bar         bar
```

For my purposes the first and second records are the same because they refer to the same two events just in a different order.  (event 1 and event 5).  I want to query this table and get all the data BUT only one record for the combination of event 1 and event 5 (i want, in this case a result set containing either the 1st and 3rd records or the 2nd and 3rd record).

I'd like to do this without pre-processing the data (avoid looping through data, etc)

Suggestions?

Comment: I appreciate your propensity for flirting with uncertainty, but in this instance I think you have to decide whether you want the first row OR the second row, and what the criteria might be for making that decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name o,
WHERE o.eventid_1 <= o.eventid_2 OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_name i
    WHERE i.eventid_1 = o.eventid_2
    AND i.eventid_2 = o.eventid_1
);
```

But if the order of `eventid_1` and `eventid_2` don't matter for *anything*, then you should really ensure that they are always stored in the table in a certain way (e.g. you should enforce `eventid_1 <= eventid_2` with a CHECK constraint (PostgreSQL has these, so I expect MySQL does too)).

**[EDIT: Fix table aliases.]**

Comment: please observe SomeInfo,MoreInfo and YetMoreInfo are **not** duplicating.. so if we select minimum value out of eventid1 and eventid2 in first output column and maximum value out of eventid1 and eventid2 in second output column, I am afraid, it will be giving three rows as output.

Comment: @pratikgarg: My old query would have given *two* rows as output, not three -- but it was still wrong because it should have been giving one!

Comment: sir .. that will be giving three (all record) but desired output should be having two record only ..

Comment: @pratikgarg: Ah, I misunderstood you, sorry.  Yes, the total number of rows from my original, broken query would have been 3 instead of the correct 2.  (In my previous comment I was talking only about the subset of rows that are duplicates, but I wasn't clear about that.)

Comment: Great suggestion.  Thank you.  Of course using the aliases outer and inner for the tables does not work as they are reserved in MySQL (and other SQL flavors too, I assume).  Using innertable and outertable works fine--as would i and o or whatever.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat: Whoops, fixed.  BTW I see you have 17 questions but no upvotes.  Please upvote answers you find helpful.

Comment: Ah, that's what up-votes are for.  Done.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use following query for the same -

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table_name t1,
       table_name t2
WHERE  t1.eventid_1 <> t2.eventid_2
AND    t1.eventid_2 <> t2.eventid_1

UNION

SELECT t1.*
FROM   table_name t1,
       table_name t2
WHERE  t1.eventid_1 = t2.eventid_2
AND    t1.eventid_2 = t2.eventid_1
AND    t1.eventid_1 < t1.eventid_2
```

In the case given in question this query should get first and third rows.

Comment: Even just the first query (i.e. the part before `UNION`) will return many bogus rows, e.g. a row with t1.eventid_1 = 1 and t2.eventid_2 = 9.

Comment: @j_random_hacker this query will not give you any additional rows which are not present in table, and if table has that type of record where eventid_1 = 1 and eventid_2 = 9, i believe this record also desired.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Please correct me if my understanding with your comment is wrong.

Comment: The first query is a Cartesian product of `table_name` with itself, with the only restrictions being the 2 `<>` conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  Consider the 1st and 3rd rows in the OP's example table, and verify that this pair of rows satisfies these 2 `<>` conditions: therefore it will be output, which is undesirable.  In general, if `table_name` contains n rows, then that first query will output nearly n^2 rows.

Comment: @j_random_hacker ,, yes sir .. as per self join first table join will return with n*n rows .. but as we have two condition to separate or filter the data, this will only give the record where we don't have any duplication with respect to eventid1 and eventId2 swapped rows - means in the records mentioned in question, this first query should be showing only one record (third one) where it is not having any duplicate

Comment: I'm afraid it won't -- please manually check those 2 conditions for the case where the row that t1 supplies to the JOIN is the 1st row and the row that t2 supplies to the JOIN is the 3rd row.  In fact that first query will erroneously produce *2* output (joined) rows, since it will also produce a row for the case in which t1 supplies row #3 and t2 supplies row #1.

Comment: Correct .. the first query will be giving even more records  .. .